# 2 bitcoin transactions are stuck on mempool, one is CPFP

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-development

I use BlueWallet and I have two pending bitcoin transaction
One outgoing
One incoming

The outgoing transaction is a CPFP

Both the ancestors and descendants transaction are stuck for hours now

How can I hasten or drop the transaction